# Final keystroke not displayed in Javascript game

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a psychic game (Guess of which letter I'm thinking) in Javascript, and my final keystroke (guess) isn't displaying in "Predictions". Also, my "Remaining Attempts" stops at 1, rather than zero. I'm not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here's my code:

```js
//global variables
var computerChoices = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

var wins = 0;
var losses = 0;
var guessesLeft = 10;
var guessesSoFar = [];

// randomizes computer choice
var computerSelection = computerChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerChoices.length)];

//starting the game
document.onkeyup = function(start) {

    // bypasses the case requirement
    var userGuess = String.fromCharCode(start.keyCode).toLowerCase();

    // log user guess- no repeats and character must be in the alphabet
    if (guessesSoFar.indexOf(userGuess) < 0 && computerChoices.indexOf(userGuess) >= 0) {
        guessesSoFar[guessesSoFar.length]=userGuess;
        guessesLeft--;
    }

    else if (userGuess === computerSelection) {
        wins++;
        alert('The force is strong with you!');
        guessesLeft = 10;
        guessesSoFar = [];
        computerSelection = computerChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerChoices.length)];
    }

    else if (guessesLeft === 0) {
        losses++;
        alert('Better luck next time!');
        guessesLeft = 10;
        guessesSoFar = [];
        computerSelection = computerChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerChoices.length)];
    }

    // transfers info into the html
    var html =
        "<p id='wins'>Intuitive<br>Victories:<br>" + wins + "</p>" +
        "<p id='losses'>Incorrect<br>Guesses:<br>" + losses + "</p>" +
        "<p id='attempts'>Remaining<br>Attempts:<br>" + guessesLeft + "</p>" +
        "<p id='guesses'>Predictions:<br> " + guessesSoFar.join(", ") + "</p>";

    document.querySelector('#game').innerHTML = html;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code with this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="keystrokeJSgame.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The reason you dont see the remaining attempts of 0 or your last guess show up is that you are resetting these values in javascript in either the victory or loss scenario with this code (prior to updating the HTML):

```
else if (userGuess === computerSelection) { //Change from else if --> if
    wins++;
    alert('The force is strong with you!');
    guessesLeft = 10;
    guessesSoFar = [];
    computerSelection = computerChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerChoices.length)];
}

else if (guessesLeft === 0) {
    losses++;
    alert('Better luck next time!');
    guessesLeft = 10;
    guessesSoFar = [];
    computerSelection = computerChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerChoices.length)];
}
// transfers info into the html
var html =
    "<p id='wins'>Intuitive<br>Victories:<br>" + wins + "</p>" +
    "<p id='losses'>Incorrect<br>Guesses:<br>" + losses + "</p>" +
    "<p id='attempts'>Remaining<br>Attempts:<br>" + guessesLeft + "</p>" +
    "<p id='guesses'>Predictions:<br> " + guessesSoFar.join(", ") + "</p>";

document.querySelector('#game').innerHTML = html;
```

So the HTML will never show your last attempt or prediction since the game data is being reset by the win/loss condition. Its really a question now of what you would want the user to see. You could show the last prediction and guesses count but then you should not be immediately resetting the game. Perhaps ask the user if he wants to play a new game? Or start a new game after a delay? Otherwise the code seems to work fine.

There is however a problem with the victory condition (first'else if'). This should be changed to an 'if' since currently this code will never be reachable (so its currently impossible to win).  If the guess is a new & valid guess (satisfying conditions of the first if-statement which a winning guess would be expected to satisfy) the first else if will be skipped.

Comment: Thank you for your fast and thorough response, Danny! This is my first attempt at JavaScript, and so far, it’s been challenging... I appreciate the explanation and pointers! I will fix this immediately :)

Comment: No problem, please accept the answer if you feel it is correct!

Comment: So sorry, this is my first exchange here. I clicked on the green check mark- if I’ve missed a step, please let me know! Your answer is correct :)